# Magento Connect: Console output frame missing? after 1.9.2.4 update attempt

Tags: magento-1.9, error, magento-connect, conflict, console

I recently installed a new Magento-1.9.2.3 store and I went to update to the latest 1.9.2.4 releases.  I decided to start with the Mage_Downloader first, and upon committing to the install this is what it looks like at the bottom of the page along with errors of course.

> CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Mage_Downloader 1.9.2.4 conflicts with: community/Mage_All_Latest 1.9.2.3

[image]

Has anyone seen this?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I tried this once... Mage_Downloader should just be whatever version you're currently on. Due to various dependencies, a bunch of items will complain when you try to upgrade them without getting the other things at the same time.

Since you're on a new site, you should do the `Mage_All_Latest` and let it do all the heavy lifting - which will grab all the updates, including updating itself.

Answer (score 1):

I got same issue when upgrading from 1.9.2.3 to 1.9.2.4...

> Package community/Lib_Mage 1.9.2.4 conflicts with:
>   community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.2.3

Comment: any ideas on solving this?